# What's the path to import SCSS files, using Encore?

Tags: symfony, import, sass, path

I am using Webpack with Encore under Symfony. I have enable SassLoader, uncommenting `.enableSassLoader()`, and renamed `assets/css/app.css` into `assets/css/app.scss`.

I have modified the require in assets/js/app.js from `../css/app.css` to `../css/app.scss`.

Until now, it works. Style file is compiled in `public/build/app.css`

BUT I have a lot of parts SCSS files to import (one includes variables, an other ones mixins, an other one the HTML reset etc.).

So when I try to use (for example, I took only one, and I placed it in the same directory than `app.scss`:

```
@import "header"
```

Or

```
@import "header.scss";
```

It doesn't work! Neither import works.

I have tried to add, in my app.js:

```
require('../css/header.scss');
```

Above the working:

```
require('../css/app.scss');
```

Still doesn't work.

I have tried to add, in `webpack.config.js`:

```
.addEntry('header', './assets/js/header.js')
```

Comment: Does your fragments name begin with an underscore? In my case, I have the file `_vars.scss`, and simply doing `@import "vars";` is working fine.

Comment: If my comment above isn't your problem, please arrange your code. Add your `webpack.config.js` (without comments), add your js and css files listed with `addEntry()`, and add a screenshot of your assets folder hierarchy.

Comment: @Massya92: Have you added .enableSassLoader() in webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please post your solution as an answer, check it (and remove your edit), so communauty helpers do not loose time on your question :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It was very stupid !

In my imported scss file 'header', I called @extends .wrapper, which didn't existed yet because it was in an other file I had commented! I didn't read error message in my termimal ^^

Thank for your help everybody

Answer (score 0):

Massya92: Have you added .enableSassLoader() in webpack.config.js ?